# Password cracker for .zip files not giving an error. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, brute-force

My .zip -file password cracker stops at line 53 (`z.extract(Item)`) without an error message. The passwords are being made, but I am not sure what is going on.

```
import zipfile

input("press enter to start...")

#characterlist
Charlist = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
Com = [] #complete combination list 

#error handling
while True:
    try:
        rg = int(input("Range of char: ")) #how big is the password
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please use an integer")
        print( )

#calculation of all possible tries
total = 26**rg

print( )
print("thease are all the possible outcomes with the amount of characters the password has")
print(total)
print( )

#combination
for current in range(int(rg)):
    Alph = [i for i in Charlist]
    for x in range(current):
        Alph = [y + i for i in Charlist for y in Alph] #the combination
    Com = Com + Alph

#zipfile error handling
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Zipfile name: ") #the name of the zip file that has the locked items in
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(file + ".zip") #the zip name + the .zip
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File was not found (ps. do not add .zip to the end of the zip file name)")
        print( )

#number of tries
Tr = 0
Item = input("Name of file that is secured + its type (eg: .txt): ") #the file that you want to crack

for password in Com:
    try:
        Tr += 1 #incrementation of tries
        z.setpassword(password.encode('ascii')) #setting password
        z.extract(Item)
        print(f'Passcode was found, the passcode was {password}') #from here to the end area isn't being read :(
        print(f'It was found at try number {Tr}')
        break
    except:
        pass

input("press enter to close...")
```

The "error" message:

```
Zipfile name: example
Name of file that is secured + its type (eg: .txt): example.txt
press enter to close...
>>>
```

It finishes without giving feedback, nor doing anything. What was supposed to happen:

```
Zipfile name: example
Name of file that is secured + its type (eg: .txt): example.txt
Passcode was found, the passcode was 'example'
It was found at try number 'x'
press enter to close...
>>>
```

Comment: I guess this would happen if the password is not in the list of generated passwords? You could try to add an `else` clause to your `for` loop, telling the user that the password was not found. It will execute if the loop finishes without a `break`, i.e., if the correct password is not found.

Comment: @JohanL Thank you for your help, however the password is not being found even on really simple passwords like 'aa'... and weirdly enough the passwords are being made.

I can't send a screenshot but here is how it looks when I ```print(Com)```:

```['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'da', 'ea', 'fa', 'ga', 'ha', 'ia', 'ja'...```. Maybe I misunderstood what you meant, in case I got it wrong I apologize.

Comment: I think it will be `z.extract(item,pwd = password)` instead of `z.setpassword(password.encode('ascii')) z.extract(Item)`

Comment: Your `except: pass` is probably hiding the exception that is causing the program to not work. Except: pass` is in general very bad practice. Make it accept and pass for the specific ‘bad password’ exception and then you’ll see other exceptions.